# Unit tests must locate in the same package?

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing

A JUnit book says " protected method ... this is one reason the test classes are located in the same package as the classes they are testing"

Can someone share their experience on how to organize the unit tests and integration tests (package/directory wise)?

Answer (score 16):

I prefer the [maven directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). It helps you separate the test sources and test resources from your application sources in a nice way and still allow them to be part of the same package.

I use this for both maven and ant based projects.

```
  project
    |
    +- src
        |
        +- main
        |    |
        |    +- java // com.company.packge (sources)
        |    +- resources
        |
        +- test
             |
             +- java // com.company.package (tests)
             +- resources
```

Answer (score 15):

in my build process, the source directories are

```
java/src
java/test/unit
java/test/integration
```

The test and the source code are in different paths, but the packages are the same

```
java/src/com/mypackage/domain/Foo.java
java/test/unit/com/mypackage/domain/FooTest.java
java/test/integration/com/mypackage/domain/FooTest.java
```